# Difference between Celery and Gunicorn workers?

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, worker

I'm deploying a Django app with gunicorn, nginx and supervisor.

I currently run the background workers using celery:

```
$ python manage.py celery worker
```

This is my gunicorn configuration:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="hello_app"                                  # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/webapps/hello_django/hello             # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/webapps/hello_django/run/gunicorn.sock  # we will communicte using this unix socket
USER=hello                                        # the user to run as
GROUP=webapps                                     # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=3                                     # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=hello.settings             # which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=hello.wsgi                     # WSGI module name

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source ../bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
exec ../bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --log-level=debug \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE
```

Is there a way to run celery background workers under gunicorn? Is it even referring to the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Celery and gunicorn are different things. Celery is an asynchronous task manager, and gunicorn is a web server. You can run both of them as background tasks ([celeryd](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html#init-script-celeryd) to daemonize celery), just feed them your django project.

A common way to run them is using [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/), which will make sure they stay running after you log out from the server. The celery github repo has some [sample scripts for using celery with supervisor](https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/3.1/extra/supervisord).