# docker-compose redis password via environment variable

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis, environment-variables

I'm trying to pass my redis password using `docker-compose` via environment variable but it gives me errors.

Here is part of mine `docker-compose.yml` with redis image:

```
  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis
    # command: redis-server --requirepass mypassword <--- this works as expected
    # command: redis-server --requirepass ${REDIS_PASSWORD} <-- while this does not
    command: redis-server --requirepass $${REDIS_PASSWORD} <-- and this does not work either
    volumes:
      - redis:/var/lib/redis/data
      - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    ports:
      - "6379"
    env_file:
      - .env.prod
```

My `.env.prod`:

```
REDIS_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

It gives me an error:

```
consumer: Cannot connect to redis://:**@redis:6379/0: WRONGPASS invalid username-password pair or user is disabled..
```

But if I specify password directly in `docker-compose.yml` without env variable, then it works.

Answer (score 24):

None of the answers worked for me. Here is what I ended up doing, adjusted to
the code snippet provided by OP:

```yaml
redis:
  image: redis
  container_name: redis
  command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    # - Double dollars, so that the variable is not expanded by Docker Compose
    # - Surround by quotes, so that the shell does not split the password
    # - The ${variable:?message} syntax causes shell to exit with a non-zero
    #   code and print a message, when the variable is not set or empty
    - redis-server --requirepass "$${REDIS_PASSWORD:?REDIS_PASSWORD variable is not set}"
  volumes:
    - redis:/var/lib/redis/data
    - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
  ports:
    - "6379"
  env_file:
    - .env.prod
```

I changed the `command` field, so that the command is run through the shell —
this way, `/bin/sh` can expand the `REDIS_PASSWORD` variable or exit with an
error message, if the variable could not be find.

As for why the code snippet in question does not work:

1. `command: redis-server --requirepass ${REDIS_PASSWORD}`

   In this case, the `${REDIS_PASSWORD}` would be expanded by Docker Compose.
   Docker Compose first tries to find an environment variable called
   `REDIS_PASSWORD`. Then, Docker Compose looks for file `.env` (yes, even if
   the `env_file` field was provided). Because the variable is defined in file
   `.env.prod`, Compose cannot find it.
2. `command: redis-server --requirepass $${REDIS_PASSWORD}`

   Here, `${REDIS_PASSWORD}` is passed unexpanded to the `redis-server` command.
   This is because Docker runs the `redis-server` command *directly*, not
   through the shell. When one enters that command in a terminal emulator, the
   shell, usually Bash, expands the variable before running the command.

#### Sources

- [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) — the `${variable:?message}` syntax
- [Environment variables in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) — how Compose expands variables

Comment: this worked for me. i tried the 1 & 2 mentioned as well but neither worked. needed to use the solution with `/bin/sh` & `-c` as well :)

Answer (score 15):

This should work:

```yaml
    redis:
        image: redis
        command: >
          --requirepass ${REDIS_PASSWORD}
```

Comment: proper way as documented (https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/redis/)
is to provide an variable ->
environment:
      - REDIS_PASSWORD=yourpass

What you provided does not work, I'm getting  exec: --: invalid option

Comment: @syberkitten pay attention to the fact that your link does not correspond to Redis official image on Docker hub. Your solution doesn't seem to work with the official image, but the answer of Cezary Drożak did the trick for me

Comment: @syberkitten your link refers to the bitnami version

Answer (score 13):

This works for me.
Similar like *Cezary Drożak* answer, but less code.

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    restart: always
    command: /bin/sh -c "redis-server --requirepass $$REDIS_HOST_PASSWORD"
    env_file:
      - redis.env
```

`redis.env`

```
REDIS_HOST_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

[Source](https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/issues/1608)

Answer (score 4):

`env_file` allows to set environment variables in the container - while you need them in the environment of docker-compose in order to perform variable substitution for `${REDIS_PASSWORD}`.

To achieve your goal remove the `env_file` from your yml and, either:

- rename your `.env.prod` file to just `.env`, so that docker-compose would automatically pick it; or,
- specify it while calling docker-compose, by way of the `--env-file` parameter:

```sh
docker-compose --env-file .env.prod up
```

Answer (score 3):

- redis-stack

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:

  redis:
    container_name: redis-stack
    image: 'redis/redis-stack:latest'
    restart: unless-stopped
    #command: ["redis-server", "/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
    environment:
      REDIS_ARGS: "--requirepass root"
    volumes:
      - ./redis-data:/data
      #- ./conf/users.acl:/etc/redis/users.acl:z
      #- ./conf/redis.conf:/etc/redis/redis.conf:z
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"#redis-server
      - "8001:8001" #RedisInsight
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the Env vars and pass them like this:

```
  cache:
    image: redis:6.2-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      REDIS_PWD: '${REDIS_PWD}'
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    command: redis-server --save 20 1 --loglevel warning --requirepass $REDIS_PWD
    volumes:
      - cache:/data
```

Than set it in your .env file:

```
REDIS_PWD=ChangeMeLater!
```

Answer (score 1):

###### Docker Secrets

Here's a snippet for those of you who believe in Docker secrets over environment variables. If you want to be goofy and put "unusual" characters in your password then make sure you add shell quoting around `$(cat file)`. You could forgo the environment variable but using it makes the snippet more similar to what countless other Docker images provide out-of-the-box.

```yaml
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:7-alpine
    environment:
      - REDIS_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/redis_password
    secrets:
      - redis_password
    command: sh -c "redis-server --requirepass $(cat $$REDIS_PASSWORD_FILE)"

secrets:
  redis_password:
    file: .secrets/redis-password.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to set the ACL user/pass instead of global --requiredpass, it can be done by creating de redis.conf file dinamically using the environment variables at the initialization command on a custom Dockerfile:

```bash
FROM redis

CMD echo "user $REDIS_USER ~* &* +@all on >$REDIS_PASSWORD" >/etc/redis/redis.conf & redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
```